# "Max Min" in HackerRank

Tags: c, programming-challenge, sorting, time-limit-exceeded

I am trying to implement the solution for the problem ["Max Min"](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/angry-children) in HackerRank. The solution runs for some test cases but for few test cases it pops out showing "Terminated due to Time Out"

> **Problem:**
>
> Given a list of \$N\$ integers, your task is to select \$K\$ integers
>   from the list such that its unfairness is minimized.
>
> Unfairness = Max{K integer Set} - Min{K integer Set}
>
> where max denotes the largest integer among the elements of \$K\$, and
>   min denotes the smallest integer among the elements of \$K\$.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> - The first line contains an integer \$N\$.
> - The second line contains an integer \$K\$.
> - \$N\$ lines follow. Each line contains an integer that belongs to the list \$N\$.
>
> Note: Integers in the list \$N\$ may not be unique.
>
> **Output Format**
>
> An integer that denotes the minimum possible value of unfairness.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> - \$2 \le N \le 10^5\$
> - \$2 \le K \le N\$
> - \$0 \le \text{integer in} N \le 10^9\$
>
> **Sample Input #00**
>
> ```
> 7
> 3
> 10
> 100
> 300
> 200
> 1000
> 20
> 30
> ```
>
> **Sample Output #00**
>
> ```
> 20
> ```

Can anyone please point to me which part of my code is taking longer to implement and what a better solution can be?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MAX 100000
#define MAX_VAL 1000000001

int list[MAX];

int main() {

    int N, K;
    int i;
    int unfairness=0;
    scanf_s("%d %d", &N, &K);
    int set = K - 1;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        scanf_s("%d", &list[i]);
    for (int l = 0; l < N - 1; l++){
        for (int j = 0; j < N - l - 1; j++)
        {
            if (list[j] > list[j + 1])
            {
                int temp;
                temp = list[j];
                list[j] = list[j + 1];
                list[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < N - set; x++)
    {
        int differ = list[x + set] - list[x];
        //printf("Dif - %d\n", differ);
        //printf("Unfair - %d\n", unfairness);
        if (unfairness == 0){
            unfairness = differ;
        }
        else if (differ<unfairness)
            unfairness = differ;
    }
    printf("%d", unfairness);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slowness comes from the sort algorithm you've chosen. It's \$O(N^2)\$ and you can do better by using a faster sort algorithm,
such as merge sort or quicksort.
Once you do that, the solution will pass with flying colors.

---

You could simplify the loop that checks the maximum difference by initializing `unfairness` to the diff of the first interval:

```
int unfairness = list[set] - list[0];
```

And then start the loop from 1, and simplify:

```
for (int x = 1; x < N - set; x++) {
    int diff = list[x + set] - list[x];
    if (diff < unfairness) {
        unfairness = diff;
    }
}
```

Also, it would be good to put this code in a separate function.
It's good to have many short functions that do one thing,
than one long function that does many things.

---

Instead of initializing `i` at the top of the function,
it would be better to do that inside the for-loop where you use it,
just like you did for other loops.

I recommend to avoid using `l` as a variable name,
because on some displays and fonts it's too hard to distinguish from `1` or `I`.

Comment: Used Quick Sort and problem solved.. Also thanks for your other coding suggestions